# Trying to pass data from one view controller to another in a tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

so I am trying to create an array of recently viewed pictures.  Basically I have a `TableViewController` that pushes a picture view in a navigation controller, located in one tab and then am trying to have a navigation controller that records what pictures have been recently viewed, lists them in a `TableViewController` and then also pushes that to a new view displaying the picture.  I have set up both navigation controllers within the tab bar controller programmatically.  Pretty much everything is set up the way I want it but I am just not able to pass the recently viewed picture information to the table view controller that will display the list.

Here is how I am trying to pass the data when a user clicks on a particular table cell:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      RecentsTableViewController *rtvc = [[RecentsTableViewController alloc] init];
      [rtvc.recents addObject:[self dictionaryAtIndex:indexPath]];
      [rtvc release];

}
```

recents is a mutable array that I created in the `RecentsTableViewController.`  It is getting initialized ok, checked using `NSLog,` but every time a user clicks on the table cell in the other view controller, the dictionary is not being passed to the array.  I also know the dictionary information is correct and set correct because it works passing on to the view that displays the image. I guess I am just confused because I can do it for a `NavigationController`, I am just struggling to find the answer in passing data in a `TabBarController.`

Sorry if this post may be long/confusing but I have really searched everywhere for an answer with no luck.  I have heard about using the app delegate to store like a global variable but I am under the impression this is bad practice and I am trying to write my code correctly.

Here is the updated code for the dictionaryAtIndex method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *flickrPics = [FlickrFetcher photosAtPlace:self.placeID];
    NSDictionary *returnedDictionary = [flickrPics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return returnedDictionary;

}
```

Comment: you need to make an outlet, at least thats what I would do.

Comment: Do you mean to make an outlet for the MutableArray? If so, how do you go about doing that?

Comment: If you post the source to the dictionaryAtIndex method it may help debug this.

Comment: please edit your question to include that code - it's impossible to read code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[indexPath is a struct](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) which contains two properties, row and index, and cannot be used directly to access an object in an array. You probably want to do this instead:

```
[rtvc.recents updateRecents:[self dictionaryAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: When I do this, the complier gives me an error:"Passing argument 1 of 'dictionaryAtIndex:' makes pointer from integer without a cast."

Comment: Please post your method `dictionaryAtIndex`. It sounds like it might be defined oddly.

Comment: - (NSDictionary *)dictionaryAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { NSArray *flickrPics = [FlickrFetcher photosAtPlace:self.placeID]; NSDictionary *returnedDictionary = [flickrPics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; return returnedDictionary; }  **note that this does work when passing the data to the view controller that displays the pictures

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a *new* `RecentsTableViewController` (it is not the same as the one in the tab bar), setting its "recent items", and then releasing it. Nothing else has a pointer to it, so nothing else will see its "recent" items.

There are at least three easy-ish ways to update the "recents" controller:

- Access it directly from the tab bar controller (incredibly icky layering violation and breaks when you change the tab order or the navigation structure or...): `[(RecentsTableViewController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:...]) updateRecentsWithDictionary:...]`
- Post a notification, which you listen for in RecentsTableViewController: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationWithName:MyViewedPictureNotificationName object:nil userInfo:...]`
- Save it to NSUserDefaults. Load it from NSUserDefaults in `-[RecentsTableViewController viewWillAppear:]`. The advantage here is that it persists across app launches. (There is the implicit assumption that the defaults will not change while the "Recents" view is visible".)

Comment: Where should I save it to NSUserDefaults, i.e. what file/method? Does it make sense to save it each time a user clicks on a row?  I do want to save it across app launches, but I also need it to work the first time it launches.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, wouldnt just making an instance variable for RecentsTableViewController solve this problem? I have already tried that and the data still doesnt get passed to it.

Comment: Yes, if you can find the *same* instance of RecentsTableViewController. You're not, as I explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: The easiest way to use NSUserDefaults is to save everything to it whenever it changes, and load from it every time you need to read a value that might have changed. It is *not* persisted to "disk" immediately - you need to call `-synchronize`, which is automatically called on background/termination (just not if you stop it from the debugger while it's still foregrounded).

Comment: Alright so I think I finally got going in the right direction.  I used an instance variable for the class I was passing data back to and then added a few changes to how everything was created/released.  I will be incorporating NSUserDefaults once I make sure that the data is in its proper place.  Thanks for the help.